# I Keep Getting an error in my Shell Script

Tags: shell, menu, sh

I decided to make a simple game in shell script as i am new to shell script but i keep getting this error
`./Game.sh: line 4: 1: command not found`
i did everything i can to fix it but nothing really works
The Code:

```
echo "Select the Game You Want To Play!"
echo "[1] Random Number"
read gamenum
if $gamenum -eq 1 
then
    chmod +x Games/RandNum.sh
    bash Games/RandNum.sh
else
    echo "Incorrect"
    exit
fi
```

i tried to make it so that it makes us choose the game we want to play so far i only have one game.

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks. Learn `shell` instead or trying random code.

Comment: when you paste your code to shellcheck , be sure to include a "she-bang" line as the first line, usually either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`. If you're still having trouble after following the suggestions of shellcheck, the edit your question to use the "fixed" code from shellcheck. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing line 4:

```
if $gamenum -eq 1
```

to

```
if [ $gamenum -eq 1 ]
```

Also, try to read and understand the syntax of shell scripting first. (Check this useful [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash))